# Calculus equation from paper

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to understand a paper but it has an equation in it that is lost on me.. I don't think it's very advanced but unfortunately I've never had much experience with this kind of thing.

(From *The pitch of short-duration fundamental frequency glissandos*, Christophe d'Alessandro et al, [[pdf]](http://murphylibrary.uwlax.edu/digital/journals/JASA/JASA1998/pdfs/vol_104/iss_4/2339_1.pdf) -- equation below given as (1) on page 2).

$$
p = \frac{\int_{t1}^{t2} F0(\tau) d\tau}{\int_{t1}^{t2} d\tau}
$$

The accompanying text is:

> where $p$ is the pitch perceived, $F0(\tau)$ is the time-varying fundamental frequency, $t1$ and $t2$ are the averaging time limits.

Any pointers?

Comment: It's just a time-average of a function over a time interval $[t_1,t_2]$.

Comment: [Mean of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean#Mean_of_a_function) at Wikipedia.

Comment: I wish you mentioned the paper you saw this in to begin with...

Comment: @J.M. "The pitch of short-duration fundamental frequency glissandos" Christophe d'Alessandro et al http://murphylibrary.uwlax.edu/digital/journals/JASA/JASA1998/pdfs/vol_104/iss_4/2339_1.pdf - the equation in question is marked as (1) on page 2.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please edit that into your question?